# How to perform Add/Edit on class component using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

This is My class Component in jsx file now what i have to do for **Add/Edit** operation.

I want to reuse created class component for both operation with state handle.

**Here is the code :**

```
  class AddUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(foProperties) {
        super(foProperties);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="horizontal-form style1" method="post">
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <input ref={c => this.inUserId = c} type="hidden"></ input>

                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label className="control-label">First Name: </label>
                                        <input id="stFirstName" type="text" ref={c => this.props.loUser.stFirstName = c} className="form-control focus" maxlength="11" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label className="control-label">Last Name: </label>
                                        <input id="stLastName" type="text" ref={c => this.props.loUser.stLastName = c} className="form-control" maxlength="11" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label className="control-label">UserName: </label>
                                        <input id="stUserName" type="text" ref={c => this.props.loUser.stUserName = c} className="form-control" maxlength="11" placeholder="User Name" tabindex="3"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label className="control-label">Password: </label>
                                        <input id="stPassword" type="text" ref={c => this.props.loUser.stPassword = c} className="form-control" maxlength="11" placeholder="Password" tabindex="4"></input>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div className="form-actions fixed-footer">
<button onClick={this.addUser} className="btn btn-success" tabindex="5" title="Add New">Add New</button>
                            &nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <button type="button" className="btn default" tabindex="29" title="Cancel" onClick={this.props.closePopup}>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your parent component in which you want to reuse this component.

Comment: This above code showing parent and i have to use this component inside another class.

Comment: Just show me the code in which you want to use this component. You have to pass a callback to this component so that child component updates its parent component.